# Implement a zoom as in Expression Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming, transform, scale

In Expression Blend, when you scroll the mouse wheel, the on-screen elements are zoomed in/out, focused on the position where the mouse is.

I'm trying to implement an identical zoom in my own project, however I'm having problems with it jumping around after zooming, moving the mouse and then zooming again.

So far I'm using a RenderTransform with a ScaleTransform, using the mouse co-ordinates as the centerX and centerY for the ScaleTransform.

Does anyone know how they've done it in Expression Blend?

This is what I've done so far:

```
    private void ScrollCanvasMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        double zoomAmnt = e.Delta > 0 ? 0.2 : -0.2;
        _scaleTransformAmount += zoomAmnt;

        if (_scaleTransformAmount < 0.5)
            _scaleTransformAmount = 0.5;

        Point position = e.GetPosition(ScrollCanvas);

        var scaleTransform = ScrollCanvas.RenderTransform as ScaleTransform;
        if (scaleTransform == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("scaleTransform");

        scaleTransform.ScaleX = _scaleTransformAmount;
        scaleTransform.ScaleY = _scaleTransformAmount;
        scaleTransform.CenterX = position.X;
        scaleTransform.CenterY = position.Y;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of zoom is nice so i tried to implement it once, the maths of it are a bit weird, it took me about two days to figure something out that worked, this might be rather ugly code though (variables with `_` are fields on the zoom control):

```
Point cursorPos = e.GetPosition(this);
Point newCenter = _scaleT.Inverse.Transform(_translateT.Inverse.Transform(cursorPos));
Point oldCenter = new Point(_scaleT.CenterX, _scaleT.CenterY);
Vector oldToNewCenter = newCenter - oldCenter;
_scaleT.CenterX = newCenter.X;
_scaleT.CenterY = newCenter.Y;
_translateT.X += oldToNewCenter.X * (_scaleT.ScaleX - 1.0);
_translateT.Y += oldToNewCenter.Y * (_scaleT.ScaleY - 1.0);

_scalingAnimation.From = _scaleT.ScaleX;
if (e.Delta > 0)
{
    _scalingAnimation.To = _scaleT.ScaleX * ZoomScaleChangeFactor;
}
else
{
    _scalingAnimation.To = _scaleT.ScaleX / ZoomScaleChangeFactor;
}
_scaleT.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, _scalingAnimation);
_scaleT.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, _scalingAnimation);

this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
```

The order of the transforms is important of course:

```
TransformGroup tGroup = new TransformGroup();
tGroup.Children.Add(_scaleT);
tGroup.Children.Add(_translateT);
```

Comment: Ok, this is a radically different way than I'd ever envisioned trying, but I'll give it a go! What type is the `_scalingAnimation` field?

Comment: Don't worry I made it a `DoubleAnimation` and that seemed to work. As for the overall effect, it's close to what I wanted, but not quite. I'm finding that you can't really zoom in to something half way, then switch the zoom "focus" to a different area very effectively; it moves ever so slightly in the right direction but after a while my focus point goes off the screen.

Comment: Really? That never happened to me, maybe you get the point from a different control than the one the transformations are applied on or something?

Comment: I don't suppose I can be cheeky and ask for a *.xaml / *.cs file pair that is a "complete" solution working the way you see it, I think the problem may be to do with my implementation of the above code.

Comment: I just tested it more a bit more extensively just now and it turns out you are right, there is a drifting problem. I have no idea how to get rid of that though...

Comment: @Siyfion: Actually it only seems to behave weirdly if the content of the zoom control is not fitting the control's space, e.g. an `Image` control without stretching. Also the transforms are applied to the contents of the control, not the control itself. Anyway, here's the full control code: http://www.mediafire.com/?903ctx9j40e0yga

Comment: @Siyfion: Do with it what you want, but if bad things happen that is your problem, etc. I noticed that the code is quite the crap as it directly transforms the content while it should apply the transformation to a container in its template instead...

Comment: Not a problem, it's a help! :D

Comment: @Siyfion: If you fix the implementation by making the `ContentPresenter` in the default template an "[official part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx)" of the template, then find it in `ApplyTemplate` and apply the transform to that instead it seems to work fine for all content.